# How limit cpu usage from specific process?

Tags: c++, windows, process, cpu

How i can limit cpu usage to 10% for example for specific process in windows C++?

Comment: just one of the new 10 core cpus and write the process single-threaded... ;-P

Comment: Run something else that uses Flash or Silverlight at the same time - that is guaranteed to deny all other processes any more than about 10% CPU. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Sleep(x)` - will slow down your program execution but it will free up CPU cycles
Where x is the time in milliseconds

Comment: +1 Though I have an aversion to Sleep, this is probably the best thing you can do, as it really gives up CPU time (albeit in a very uncontrollable manner). `SwitchToThread` may be an alternative.

Comment: @Rin: I don't see what multithreading has to do with it. Sleep takes effect on a per-thread basis. This is a common technique to prevent a thread hammering a CPU, if it's not doing a _time-critical_ piece of work.

Answer (score 2):

This is rarely needed and maybe thread priorities are better solution but since you asked, what you should is:

1. do a small fraction of your "solid" work i.e. calculations
2. measure how much time step 1) took, let's say it's `twork` milliseconds
3. `Sleep()` for `(100/percent - 1)*twork` milliseconds where `percent` is your desired load
4. go back to 1.

In order for this to work well, you have to be really careful in selecting how big a "fraction" of a calculation is and some tasks are hard to split up. A single fraction should take somewhere between 40 and 250 milliseconds or so, if it takes less, the overhead from sleeping and measuring might become significant, if it's more, the illusion of using 10% CPU will disappear and it will seem like your thread is oscillating between 0 and 100% CPU (which is what happens anyway, but if you do it fast enough then it looks like you only take whatever percent). Two additional things to note: first, as mentioned before me, this is on a **thread** level and not **process** level; second, your work must be real CPU work, disk/device/network I/O usually involves a lot of waiting and doesn't take as much CPU.

Comment: I need to set cpu limit on not my process, so i can set limit in this process unfortunately ((

Comment: well, what you want is simply not possible

Answer (score 1):

That is the job of OS, you can not control it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't limit to exactly 10%, but you can reduce it's priority and restrict it to use only one CPU core.

Comment: Careful with playing on priorities, this will not at all do what you think. A thread with a lower priority will still use 100% CPU if no higher priority thread is "ready". However, as long as any thread with a higher priority is "ready", it will not run at all.